# Find the factorization of the following numbers in Z[i]. 11 + i ; 510 + 180i:

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integers

The factorization of the following numbers in Z[i].

- 11 + i
- 510 + 180i

Usually to determine the factorization of a number x we would find its prime factorization say $x=y*z$. Then, we would determine the solution to $a^2+b^2 = y $ and $a^2+b^2 = z $. But how do we determine the factorization of complex numbers such as the examples above?

Comment: Have you done *any* examples like this before, e.g., factoring $3+4i$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$?

Comment: Hint: Start by factorizing norms to see possible candidates

Comment: @KCd i have not. I've solved the factorization of integers such as 65 but not complex numbers yet

Comment: @lhf what do u mean by factorizing the norms. For example, the norm of 11+ i is: N(11+i)= 122 if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes. The norm is multiplicative: $N(z\cdot w)=N(z)\cdot N(w)$, so any factorization gives a factorization of the norms.

Comment: $N(11+i)= 122 = 2 \cdot 61$. Now, what Gaussian integers have norm $2$ or $61$? Start with norm $2$.

Comment: As others have said, you get a big clue by factoring the norm.  For example, $3+4i$ has norm $25 = 5^2$, and the Gaussian primes with norm $5$ are $1 \pm 2i$ (up to unit multiple). So try all three options of multiplying two terms to get something with norm $25$: $(1+2i)(1+2i) = -3 + 4i$, $(1-2i)(1-2i) = -3 - 4i$, and $(1+2i)(1-2i) = 5$. Since $-3-4i = -(3+4i)$, we get $3+4i = -(-3-4i) = -(1-2i)^2$, so that's a prime factorization of $3+4i$ (up to unit multiple).

Comment: See page 15 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf for that example worked out again and the prime factorization of $2319+1694i$ worked out.